# VSCode не видит модуль если открыть файл в папке, но видит если открыть файл как файл

Tags: vue.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

писал плагин для Vencord (по сути он представляет из себя react приложение). Есть скрипт в папке `PluginFolder/index.tsx`.

Так вот, если открыть этот скрипт, то все подсказки и вся подсветка работает корректно, все модули видны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если открыть проект как `PluginFolder`, и уже из него выбрать файл, то VSC не видит общий скоуп, хотя по сути файл один и тот же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если что, то в первом случае он именно видит ВЕСЬ скоуп, так как подсказки видят все @utils/*

Как это можно исправить?

**EDIT:** То же самое и без плагинов для VUE и react. Похоже сбоит встроенная в VSC `TypeScript JSX` подсветка